# Redirect to new Page in AngularJS using $location

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I am testing with the following AngularJS $location. I don't what's the problem with this. Just want to check if the redirection is working or not:

**HTML**

```
<body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   Hello {{name}}!
   <button ng-click='go()'>Go</button>
</body>
```

**AngularJS code**

```
var app = angular.module('location', []);
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams, $location) {
   $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.go = function() {
   $location.absUrl() = 'http://www.google.com';
   }
});
```

Comment: Is there a typo `==`, it should be `=`

Comment: You could always use: window.location = 'http://www.google.com'

Answer (score 145, accepted):

$location won't help you with external URLs, use the $window service instead:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Note that you could use the window object, but it is bad practice since $window is easily mockable [whereas window is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922356/315601).

Comment: nice touch with $window instead of window. this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: $window is the an extra module to be added to use the $window feature?

Comment: @GK123512648 no need, it is located in the core ns module as mentioned in the official [API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Comment: I had to use `$window.location = ...`, without the `.href`.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change ng-view you'll have to use the '#'

```
$window.location.href= "#operation";
```

Comment: when I used this it generate the following error (although it worked): JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: or you can just call $location.path('/whatever/the/path/is')

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
$location.absUrl() == 'http://www.google.com';
```

is wrong. First == makes a comparison, and what you are probably trying to do is an assignment, which is with simple = and not double ==.

And because absUrl() getter only. You can use url(), which can be used as a setter or as a getter if you want.

reference : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location

Comment: I Didnt get using '='. Also in the documentation examples they have specified '=='

Comment: Won't work !!! absURL is READONLY. $location service provides getter methods for read-only parts of the URL (absUrl, protocol, host, port) and getter / setter methods for url, path, search, hash

Answer (score 6):

It might help you!

AngularJs Code-sample

```
var app = angular.module('urlApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $window) {
    $scope.ClickMeToRedirect = function () {
        var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/Account/Login";
        $log.log(url);
        $window.location.href = url;
    };
});
```

HTML Code-sample

```
<div ng-app="urlApp">
    <div ng-controller="urlCtrl">
        Redirect to <a href="#" ng-click="ClickMeToRedirect()">Click Me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me inside a directive and works without refreshing the baseurl (just adds the endpoint).Good for Single Page Apps with routing mechanism.

```
  $(location).attr('href', 'http://localhost:10005/#/endpoint')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try entering the url inside the function

```
$location.url('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: This doesn't work (at least in Angular 1.2.8), it's simply appending `http://www.google.com` to the URL.  `$window.location.href` seems to be working though.