# AngularJS routing to different page

Tags: angularjs, redirect

In Angular, how do I redirect to a different page? With all the examples I've found, it only redirects to a relative URL, i.e. my currentURL+'#/new_newPath'.

Here is my code:

```
function mainController($scope, $http, $location) {

    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createProperty = function() {
        $http.post('/api/property', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data){
                $location.path( '/profile' );
            })
            .error(function(data){
            });
    };
}
```

I am originally at localhost/new_prop and i want to go to localhost/profile.
Also, my angular app is located at localhost/new_property. if i go to localhost, i am not accessing my angular app. localhost/profile is also not part of the angular app

This seems like it should be really straightforward....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do

```
$window.location.href = '/profile';
```

Since $window will cause the reloading of the page.

The [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location) says about `$location`:

> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed.
>   To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API,
>   `$window.location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [**`$window`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) not `$location`.

`$window` contains `location.href` try setting that.

```
$window.location.href = '/profile';
```

You can refer to this post: [Redirect to new Page in AngularJS using $location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875467/redirect-to-new-page-in-angularjs-using-location) for more info.