# $location.path not working in controler

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$http','$scope', function ($http, $scope, $location) {        

    $location.path("Home/Index");


}]);
```

browser give error that $location in undefined, how I troubleshoot it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not add `$location` to dependency notation:

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$http','$scope', '$location', function ($http, $scope, $location) {
    $location.path("Home/Index");   
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks it now working but in the url has '#'  like following
http://localhost:57188/#/Home/Index how it solve it

Comment: @DineshPipple Take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875467/redirect-to-new-page-in-angularjs-using-location