# Redirect to another HTML page in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've written a simple Login form with no actual server. Just a hard coded login credentials. And if they credentials are matching on angular controller function then I need to show another HTML page. On '/login.html', following code is written

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Login</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/InfoGraph/js/angular/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/InfoGraph/js/angular/angular-route.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/InfoGraph/js/login.js" ></script>  
</head>

<body class="gray-bg" ng-app="login">

    <div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen  animated fadeInDown">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="logo-name">IGraph</h1>
            </div>
            <h3>Welcome to IGraph</h3>           
            <form class="m-t" role="form" name="loginToIGraph" ng-controller="LoginController as login">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" ng-model="user.username" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" ng-model="user.password" >
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" ng-click="login.loginUser(user)">Login</button>
                <a href="#"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
                <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Do not have an account?</small></p>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="register.html">Create an account</a>
            </form>           
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And in '`login.js`' the code is following :

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('login',[]);

app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location)
    {
        $scope.loginUser = function(user){
            if(user.username == 'demo' && user.password == 'demo'){
               $location.href('/afterLogin.html');
            }
            else{
                alert('Wrong credentials')
            }
        }

    }]);

})();
```

But on `$location.href('/afterLogin.html');` , it does nothing. Even there is no error. What could be the cause?

Comment: don't use $location, use window.location

Comment: does `$location.path(url)` work ?

Comment: you should use $window.location.href for a redirection and if you check the $location documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location, you could see that href does  not exist, then use $location.path(...) but i think here you want $window.location.href

Comment: I would suggest you to use routes / ng-view. That would be a more "Angular way" to achieve that.

Comment: I've tried this. But there is nothing. No error and no success. the link does nothing if my credentials are correct.

Comment: @enguerranws Can you please give me a proper example of how to use routes/ ng-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try like this below:

```
 var path = "/afterLogin.html";
 window.location.href = path;
```

Comment: This will work for sure, but in Angular is better to use their services/utils. Because you could mock those calls inside tests.

Comment: You are correct. But putting these lines inside a function and then mocking that function by stub will also help to unit test properly. Anyway i am not sure about angularjs service for redirecting.

Comment: Super dude. But this is pure javascript syntax. I am not sure if some proper angular services available to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the angular [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window).
just like sms said in previous answer for redirection.

Another way is through Routing - [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.
[Redirect to new Page in AngularJS using $location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875467/redirect-to-new-page-in-angularjs-using-location)

```
Giving proper path will help you I think.
```

Comment: Hi @Reds , Both files exists in a same location in my project folder only. What could be the correct path.

Comment: may be You should try different combos of only" ." or "./" or "/." or "../"

Comment: Hey it worked. The path it required was with main project folder.