# Angular loading page without template

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have a SPA that uses angular routing. I would like to have a certain link that will open a specific page (not using a template) when clicked.

In other words I would to have some links that simply act as  regular links and redirect the user to a new page. I don't want these links load inside of the template.

Surely this has to be possible right?

Many Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you wanna replace the enitre current page with a redirect to a new external page?
If that so, you can definately do that using $location service just a s follows:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Just put that into an ng-click, then inject the `$location` service into your controller and you are good to go.

Further documentation on :

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

similar question on :

> [Redirect to new Page in AngularJS using $location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875467/redirect-to-new-page-in-angularjs-using-location)

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought of putting that into an ngClick!! Perfect! Thank you!