# Clickable jumbotron background image

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a jumbotron background image,i want the image clickable.         when i made a click on image it should redirect to another page.How can i do this?

```
<div class="jumbotron">

</div>

.jumbotron{
background:url(../images/jumb.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angular-js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875467/redirect-to-new-page-in-angularjs-using-location

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```css
.jumbotron{
background:url('../images/jumb.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com"><div  class="jumbotron">
</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply **wrap your jumbotron inside an anchor tag** and give a definite path to the `href` attribute of that anchor tag. Rest of the code is perfect as it is. Like so

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <div class="jumbotron">

  </div>
</a>
```

The optional attribute `target="_blank"` opens the link in a new tab instead of the same. Just remove it if not needed.

*NOTE: The `http://` protocols are important here or otherwise it will redirect to that URL say `www.google.com` inside your current project directory.*