# Mock window.location.reload in Jasmine testing

Tags: mocking, jasmine, window.location

I have created a `window.location.reload` function in my javascript.

I need to mock the reload function while testing in Jasmine since it keeps on looping.

The test goes well when I run `grunt jenkins`. But not while testing in the browser (mozilla/chrome).

Here is my code snippet.

Javascript:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Jasmine Test:

```
spyOn(window.location, 'reload').and.callFake(function(){});
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: `window.location.reload` is not a writable property, so the browser won't let a spy override it. To get around this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919370/jasmine-mock-window-object

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for sharing your views.

I did a work around as suggested and it was successful.

Since window is a browser object and cannot be spied upon, I just wrapped the function in JavaScript and referred that function in my test spec.

Javascript code:

```
var function = windowReload(){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

call the function `windowReload()` where required.

Jasmine Test:

```
spyOn(obj, 'windowReload').andCallFake(function(){});
```

Comment: this function should be private. and then you don't test it. running in circles...

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `$window` instead of `window`.

Try this:

```
$window = jasmine.createSpy('$window');
```

or just make your own:

```
$window = {location:{reload:function(){}}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just meet the same issue. window.location = '' cause inf loop while run in browser.
A simple solution is set window.location = '#' to stop reload.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me in BeforeEach with Jamine

```
delete window.location;
window.location = Object.create(window);
window.location.reload = () => {};
spyOn(window.location, 'reload');
```

and this worked using Jest

```
delete window.location;
window.location = Object.create(window);
window.location.reload = jest.fn();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can always do:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  window.reload = () => console.log('Mock redirect');
});
```

Respectively:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => console.log('Mock redirect');
  window.open = () => console.log('Mock redirect');
});
```