# Karma+Jasmine: Mock external library defined on window object

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

I am developing a Javascript SDK and I am using an external library defined on the window object

```js
  private getFromATS(): string {
    return window.ats.retrieveEnvelope(function (envelope: string) {
      console.log('Located ATS.js');
      return JSON.parse(envelope).envelope;
    });
  }
```

Now I am developing some unit tests and I am trying to mock this library. So far I have tried the following which have not worked

```js
// Method 1
spyOn(window.ats, 'retrieveEnvelope').and.returnValue(function (
      callback: Callback<String>
    ) {
      return callback('{"envelope":"asdfasdfasdf"}');
    });

// Method 2
    spyOn(window, 'ats').and.returnValue({
      retrieveEnvelope: function (callback: Callback<String>) {
        return callback('{"envelope":"asdfasdfasdf"}');
      },
    });

// Method 3
    window = Object.create(window);
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'ats', {
      value: {
        retrieveEnvelope: function (callback: Callback<String>) {
          return callback('{"envelope":"asdfasdfasdf"}');
        },
      },
      writable: true,
    });

// Method 4
const windowStud = {
      ats: {
        retrieveEnvelope: function (callback: Callback<String>) {
          return callback('{"envelope":"asdfasdfasdf"}');
        },
      },
    } as Window & typeof globalThis;
```

None of these work. How can I mock an "external" property of the window object using Jasmine?

// EDIT

[This is a great solution using dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919370/jasmine-mock-window-object) but is there a way to avoid changing that main code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining it on a `beforeEach/beforeAll` and set it back to `undefined` in an `afterEach/afterAll` for the other test suites.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // set the property
  window.ats = {
      retrieveEnvelope: function (callback: Callback<String>) {
        return callback('{"envelope":"asdfasdfasdf"}');
      },
   };
});

afterEach(() => {
  // reset back to undefined
  window.ats = undefined;
});
```